# Get data using Array of specific worksheet names

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Im trying to get data from specific worksheets with in a folder containing multiple workbooks(folder may contain more than 600 workbooks sometimes).

**Example: There are 5 workbooks in a folder. I need to loop through all 5 workbooks and grab only specific sheets data to Sheet2 of main workbook. Those specific sheets names are listed in sheet1. Sheet2 is where i need to consol the data one by one.

My specific sheet names in sheet1 may vary as per my work. sometimes i need to pull only 2 sheets data, sometimes i need to pull only 4 sheets or sometimes only 1 sheet. but not more than 5 sheets.

**My Problem: Im able to pull multiple sheets data but not able to pull if i have only one specific sheet name in sheet1. The code which i tried is mentioned below. Could you please guide me where im going wrong.

Thank you soo much for the help. My apologies if i haven't explained it clearly.

```
Sub Getdata()

Dim A As Workbook
Dim B As Worksheet, B1 As Worksheet
Dim Bk As Variant, Sht As Variant
Dim rn As Range, rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set B = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set B1 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    xR = B.Range("A" & B.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LR = B1.Range("A" & B.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'assign sheet names list to rng
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & xR)
    Bk = rng
   'getfolder path using diafolder
    Set C = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False)
        For Each Sht In Bk
            Set ws = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = Worksheets(Sht)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not (ws Is Nothing) Then
             With ws
                Set rn = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Range", Type:=8)
                rn.Copy Destination:=B.Range("C" & xR)
            End With
            Else
            B.Cells(xR, "B") = "Not Found"
            End If
            xR = xR + 1
        Next
        C.Close savechanges = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Team, any concerns, doubts, with my request. i did had any suggestions, please let me know if my request is not clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question mentions *"Sheet2 is where i need to consol the data one by one."* but the code `rn.Copy Destination:=B.Range("C" & xR)` shows the copy to `Sheet 1`. Try this ;

update : allow for one sheet in list

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub macro1()

   ' check valid list on sheet 1
   Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, iLastRow As Long
   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
   iLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   If iLastRow = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No sheets on Sheet1", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
   End If

   ' select folder
   Dim Folder As String, Filename As String
   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Please select a folder"
        .Show
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort
            MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Folder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder
    End With

    ' get sheet name
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, n As Long, msg As String
    Dim dict As Object, key, ar(), rng As Range

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' put sheet1 list into array
    If iLastRow = 2 Then
        ar = Array(ws1.Range("A2").Value2) ' single sheet
    Else
        ar = Application.Transpose(ws1.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow).Value2)
    End If
    For Each key In ar
        dict(key) = 0
    Next
    
    'sheet2
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    iLastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' loop through workboks
    Filename = Dir(Folder & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Folder & Filename, True, True) ' update link, read only
        msg = ""

        ' check sheet names against list
        For Each wsSrc In wbSrc.Sheets
             n = n + 1
             ' check if name on list
             If dict.exists(wsSrc.Name) Then
                 dict(wsSrc.Name) = wsSrc.Index
             End If
        Next

        ' compile results
        For Each key In ar
            If dict(key) > 0 Then

                wbSrc.Sheets(dict(key)).Activate
                Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Range", Type:=8)
                rng.Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("C" & iLastRow + 1)
                iLastRow = iLastRow + rng.Rows.Count
                dict(key) = 0 ' reset for next workbook
                
            Else
                msg = msg & vbCr & key
            End If
        Next
        
        If Len(msg) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Sheets not exist in " & wbSrc.Name & msg, vbExclamation
        End If
        wbSrc.Close SaveChanges:=False
       
        Filename = Dir
    Loop
    MsgBox n & " Sheets scanned", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code is superb and it does what i need, what if i have only one sheet to pull. When i tried with the code it show error `Type mismatch`. on the line `For Each key In ar`. could you please guide me on this..

Comment: Thank you soo much, really that was tricky.. I accepted it as a best solution. Thank you soo much once again. Have a great day..